# react-router-dom not rendering my component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a simple registration program with react JS but got stuck when it is not able to render my App and Register component .

```
 import React from "react";
 import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
 import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
 import App from "./App";
 import Register from "./screens/Register";

 ReactDOM.render(
 <BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
   <Route path="/" exact render={(props) => <App {...props} />} />
   <Route
    path="/register"
    exact
    render={(props) => <Register {...props} />}
    />
  </Routes>
 </BrowserRouter>,
 document.getElementById("root")
 );
```

Comment: Have you got any errors on the browser console? Can you post the error please?

Comment: nothing in my terminal but on chrome I get -----> react-dom.development.js:67 Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:38252:5)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:38185:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:37665:5)
printWarning @ react-dom.development.js:67
manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.

Comment: Here is my register file --> https://pastebin.com/59diUb6Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much as I know, there isn't any prop like `render` in the `route`component of react-router@v6. There is hooks that are usable in your pages to get data related to the routing. You will find them in the [official documentation](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6).
(Consider reading the links about migration from the v5 or from react-router).

You can of course still pass regular props in your component. See an [example on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-functional-boilerplate-16-13-1-t8va6r) here and here is the code :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Link, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './style.css';

const Page1 = (props) => <Link to="page2"> {props.test} - Go to Page 2</Link>;
const Page2 = () => <Link to="/">Go to Page 1</Link>;

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" exact element={<Page1 test="Test" />} />
        <Route path="/page2" exact element={<Page2 />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: It still renders my App component but not my Register component .  Here is my register file --> pastebin.com/59diUb6Q

Comment: @Dodo96 We might need the code of you App component as well.It's probably stupid to tell you that but do you have any link in your `App` component that you use to navigate ?  I feel like you expect both the component `App` and `Register` to be displayed at the same time but if you wanna do it, it won't works this way.

Comment: here is my app file --> https://pastebin.com/Swu9PYa5

Comment: App is rendering by your given logic but not register

Comment: If your route is correct and you are using a `Link` for the routing between `App` and `Register`, then maybe it come from this line `{isAuth() ? <Navigate to='/' /> : null}` in your `Register component`. Are you sure your `isAuth` method return `false` ? Check your URL to see if you are in `/register` or just in `/`

Comment: both are now solved bro by your logic , thanks